# SSL error when updating extensions

Tags: error

I am using XAMPP.  I'm trying to download a free extension from Magento Connect and I'm getting the following error:

`community/ET_*****: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Comment: Not an answer, but a nudge in the right direction. google for the message - this is an issue with ytour server configuration. see: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

Comment: You can also just manually edit downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php and add “$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, ‘TLSv1′);” after “$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);”

Comment: @aivo editing core and lib is highly discouraged

Comment: @ReidBlomquist that would normally be true, but please explain how to write a module that works on `downloader/lib/` please? This isn't `app/core/` or `lib/`. Plus editing core and lib is how Magento patches work. They don't back up the patched files so you can revert and the patched files are overwritten, often requiring reapplying the patches over several upgrades to avoid regression failure.

Comment: It seems that Magento finally got around to Poodle fixes and disabled **SSLV3** on Magento Connect. But in a left-hand, right-hand disconnect type thing, forgot that the `downloader/` software they provide has **SSLV3** hardcoded into some curl requests it uses and didn't provide a patch.

Comment: Either way, if you're not using a VCS, I wouldn't change it. I also wouldn't change it if you can resolve it with another method. Also the argument that Magento core team releases patches that modify core and lib is just silly. They're the core team and the maintainers, doing so on your own can result in numerous issues. Adding to `/lib/` is something altogether different.

Comment: Also, don't use connect.

Comment: Yep, they're the core team that introduces regression issues when you upgrade because the patched files get overwritten and the exploitable vulnerability gets reintroduced. I realize it was silly to point that little issue out, upgrading back into a seriously wide open back door isn't going to be fixed by a VCS if you don't reapply the patch to VCS code base. And sometimes the command line `mage` use of connect is the only way to download the package for manual installation. I'm asking you to please provide an answer to "resolve it with another method" and "don't use connect" isn't the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is our problem. Magento Connect has different hardware. Please wait a bit and we'll get it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Magento now blocks SSLv3 on their servers, but Magento downloader (./mage as well), using curl tries to use SSLv3. Here is a blog post that solves this issue along with a patch file. https://www.dwdonline.com/blog/fix-magento-error14077410ssl-routinesssl23_get_server_hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure.html

This will fix the issue and allow you to install all extensions again. And no, it's actually because your server is configured properly - but Magento downloader isn't.